# Is all the nobility in Westeros permanently drunk?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Is all the nobility in Westeros permanently drunk ?

They seem to have ale or wine with every meal, even breakfast,  and often between meals.

Comment: Wine and ale/beer were commonly drunk in older times, and could be a *lot* weaker than what we'd expect today.  http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/why-did-greeks-and-romans-dilute-their-wine and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_beer.  If you're not looking for a canon answer I'll post this.

Comment: @JimmyShelter Apart from Robert Baratheon he was just a drunk.

Comment: @Simon - can't argue with that. :)

Comment: Though it's strange, but they drank for their health. They didn't want to get some stomach desease:)

Comment: If you lived in a muddy, violent world with no air conditioning, no indoor plumbing, and no toilet paper, you'd stay drunk all the time too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is very typical of a medieval society. Water was not very clean, so people drank wine or beer with every meal in place of water. For example, [Geoffrey Chaucer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Chaucer) (the author of the Canterbury Tales) was granted "a gallon of wine daily for the rest of his life" by King Edward III.

Comment: Also worth to mention that, due to using wine and beer as a "sanitizer" of water, watering of wine was usual (allowing for a proper hidratation of the body without the alcoholic intoxication). Jimmy Shelter's point of the alcoholic beverages being stonger nowadays is also right, AFAIK.

Comment: Also there's a few mentions throughout the books of rivers being used as latrines, and as things progress, chocked full of dead bodies. Pick your poison: alcoholic beverage with sanitizing properties, or water infused with corpses and feces.

Comment: According to *The Time Traveller's Guide to Medieval England* (a fine book), the "unsafe water" thing is not entirely true. People had worked out that rainwater was safe to drink, and did so if it was plentiful (as in most of northern Europe). But beer and wine had some extra nutritional value, and were just more enjoyable, so they were very popular.

Comment: See also http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11307/why-dont-people-without-access-to-clean-water-drink-beer-anymore/12755#12755 - some medieval people were quite well aware of the benefits of boiling water.  This also supports the "I drink beer because I like it" theory.

Comment: It's not just medieval societies. Various European writers were astounded by the amount of alcohol consumed by American settlers. Various tidbits can be found at http://www2.potsdam.edu/alcohol/files/Alcohol-and-Drinking-in-American-Life-and-Culture.html#.U3pQC8ZOWfA

Comment: We are speaking about wealthy people obviously. Poor people were still drinking water.

Comment: @Sulthan: Not so. [Small beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_beer) was like bread, it was part of the normal diet for ordinary people. The average peasant farmer could certainly afford beer, or make it him/herself.

Comment: While possibly apocryphal, you didn't have to be wealthy to be drinking alcohol, and it's a relatively common thing to read of children and babies being given gin in Victorian London as it's distilled qualities (rough as they were) meant it was cleaner than the water, as well as being the cheapest form of alcohol given that you could brew it from scaps.  As for strength, I think it works 2 ways, the *spirits* like Gin I think were known to be much more dilute than that of todays, but the beers, particularly *mead* which was popular in medieval times was often stronger than your average Bud.

Comment: @stuffe: Nope. Mead isn't beer at all, it's fermented honey. In the medieval era, some ales for feasts and other special occasions were pretty strong, but the "small beer" for everyday consumption was not -- typically about 2 or 3% alcohol (modern Bud is 5%). And old fashioned spirits were at least as strong as today's versions, sometimes more so -- classic British navy rum is about 80% alcohol, which is why it was heavily watered down to make "grog".

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit I tried to qualify that by saing "often" not always, and "fermented honey" is a very narrow definition, it's my understanding that  the key issue is that the majority of the fermented sugars come from honey, but not necessarily all, and they frequently use hops also.  I was merely making a distinction though, between the *harder* spirits which were often *diluted*, and the *softer* drinks, like beer, ale, mead, cider etc.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Good ol' perpetual British rain, keeping us alive

Answer (score 12):

### What's "drunk" ?

Drinking alcohol in limited amounts doesn't neccessarily make you "drunk" as per classic definition of that word. A typical adult male doesn't become drunk by drinking a pint of beer with a meal.

It will make you "drunk" as per definition of drunk driving in most western countries, since even low levels of blood alcohol content increase risk of car accidents. However, given the much lower alcohol levels of common drinks of the time, some two cups of "ale or wine with every meal, even breakfast" would result in a BAC of 0.05 percent or below, which has some relaxation and talkativeness effect (and might make you ineligible to drive nowadays in some countries), but is strictly different from the common meaning of the word "drunk" which would imply the behavior of someone with 0.15+ BAC.

There are cultures nowadays where it's common to have beer or wine with every meal, possibly including breakfast, and it doesn't make anyone "permanently drunk" by any reasonable understanding of these words.

### Not only nobility

As per the other answers, you'd expect the same habits for almost everyone else, including women and children. A nine year old daughter of a random tailor would also most likely drink small beer or watered-down wine at lunch and dinner.

Comment: +1. Also, a lot of beer was being consumed by people doing heavy manual labour. They would have sweated out much of the alcohol instead of metabolizing it, so it wouldn't make them drunk. (Not sure there are any modern cultures where wine at breakfast is considered normal, although in places like France or Italy it is commonplace for the afternoon/evening meals.)